# Separate Firebase events are being combined into a single event in DebugView & Universal Analytics (UA) reporting

Tags: android, firebase, events, firebase-analytics

In our app we're required to make multiple `add_to_cart` event calls for different products coming from the same screen. For example we call `add_to_cart` for **Movie Tickets** and another `add_to_cart` event for a concession upsell of **Popcorn + Drink**. These are required to be in separate `add_to_cart` calls because they don't share the same `item_list_name`.

The problem is the multiple `add_to_cart` events are sometimes combined into a single event in the Firebase DebugView and also show that way in Universal Analytics reporting. I've debugged the code and it's correctly separating the events in these cases and also shows correctly in the ADB command prompt debug log.

[image]

[image]

I was able to avoid the combined events by adding a Thread.Sleep(1000) before each `add_to_cart` event but I don't like this solution long-term. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the issue in two different ways. ***Language used here is C#***

1. Add a delay at the bottom of the foreach loop between each item (`Thread.Sleep`). **NOT PREFERRED**

```c#
public void AddProducts(Order order, string movieGenre)
{
    List<(List<IParcelable> items, string itemListName)> finalItemsList = BuildItemsListForAddToCartFromOrder(order, movieGenre);

    foreach (var (items, itemListName) in finalItemsList)
    {
        Bundle addToCartBundle = new Bundle();
        SetCommonEventParameters(addToCartBundle);
        addToCartBundle.PutString(AMCTheatreApp.Constants.GA.EventParameter.CartId, order.Token.ToString());
        addToCartBundle.PutDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Value, (double)order.SubTotal);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemListName))
            addToCartBundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemList, itemListName);
        addToCartBundle.PutParcelableArrayList(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Items, items);
        _firebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.AddToCart, addToCartBundle);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

2. Call another event at the end of the foreach loop so it splits the AddToCart event calls.

```c#
public void AddProducts(Order order, string movieGenre)
{
    List<(List<IParcelable> items, string itemListName)> finalItemsList = BuildItemsListForAddToCartFromOrder(order, movieGenre);

    foreach (var (items, itemListName) in finalItemsList)
    {
        Bundle addToCartBundle = new Bundle();
        SetCommonEventParameters(addToCartBundle);
        addToCartBundle.PutString(AMCTheatreApp.Constants.GA.EventParameter.CartId, order.Token.ToString());
        addToCartBundle.PutDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Value, (double)order.SubTotal);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemListName))
            addToCartBundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemList, itemListName);
        addToCartBundle.PutParcelableArrayList(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.Items, items);
        _firebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.AddToCart, addToCartBundle);

        TrackEvent("Ecommerce", "Add To Cart Combo", "Batman | Popcorn + Drink");
    }
}
```